# How can I download News feed data from Bloomberg using the xbbg python library?

Tags: excel, bloomberg, blpapi

I want it so that every time there is a new headline in red as shown in the picture:
I will be able to download the headline using the some sort of a function.
I've tried using the blp.live function but I get some random output like this `<async_generator object live at 0x000002D1D2228790>`

[News Feed Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaaoD.png)

Code I've tried:

```
from xbbg import blp
data = blp.live("NEWS", "TOP NEWS")
data_str = str(data)
print(data_str)
```

Output:

```
<async_generator object live at 0x000002D1D2228790>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: @DS_London I've updated the question and typed in my code. I think the problem I'm having is the 'ticker name' for the news feed...

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the blp.live function does. It is used for subscribing asynchronously to live tick-by-tick market data (eg BID, ASK etc) for a particular security. As far as I am aware, you can't access Bloomberg news feeds via this or any other API.

Comment: Do you think there might be a way of doing it through python only. Detecting when there's an important headline, copying it and then saving it to a file? Are you aware of any libraries that can do this?

Comment: I am not aware of any, I am afraid. You could attempt some sort of screen-scraping of the Bloomberg terminal or LaunchPad window using the clipboard and combinations of mouse move/click messages but that is a whole world of pain.

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same, but as you said, it sounds like pain. Thanks for your advice anyways!